# How to create snippet subfolders in textmate bundle

Tags: textmate

I've just discovered textmate and I love it. I would love to use it as a way of storing my own snippets. I know how to do this in textmate but as I want to add loads of snippets I don't want them to become disorganised. I would like to add them into organised subfolders under the relevant bundle. eg under the shell script bundle I would like to add a folder that keeps all my networking snippets together. I cant find anywhere how to do this but I know it can be done as some bundles are organised like this.....Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out with a lot of trial and error and starting with this Superuser [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/380371/how-do-i-create-a-new-snippet-in-textmate-2).

The only way to do it in TextMate 2.0 is to manually edit the `info.plist` file for your bundle. I suggest doing this on an exported copy of the bundle and reloading it into textmate. To export a bundle right click on the bundle in bundle editor and click `Export Bundle...`.

Start by adding a `mainMenu` section at the top level of the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    ...
    <key>mainMenu</key>
    <dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

From what I can tell, the `mainMenu` dict supports 3 keys: `excludedItems`, `items`, and `submenus`. The `excludedItems` and `items` are arrays containing a list of UUIDs of either bundle items (snippets, commands, etc.) or submenus. You can get the UUID of a command or snippet by opening it in textmate and finding the `uuid` key; it'll look like:

```
<key>uuid</key>
<string>0A2DB1AC-3049-4BD5-8931-641E716990F9</string>
```

Once you have the UUIDs of your items you can list them in `items` to populate the bundle menu in the order you wish, e.g.:

```
<key>items</key>
<array>
  <string>409b0e74-9ab5-4d35-b957-9ddf23a71c0c</string>
  <string>------------------------------------</string>
  <string>d2c991dc-a00e-4247-8479-f2d29f387319</string>
</array>
```

If you use a series of `-` characters in lieu of a UUID, it will create a separator in the menu. Likewise, if there are snippets you don't want to display in the bundle's menu you can add them to `excludedItems`.

To create submenus you have to define them inside `submenus`, like so:

```
<key>submenus</key>
<dict>
    <key>71BE58B2-E486-4B21-93F1-C208D4914099</key>
    <dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
            <string>6D0B2B9D-62C7-4842-BA28-F3379E887D93</string>
            <string>CADC55BD-0D0A-48C8-B296-35FA7AAE09CA</string>
        </array>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>C++ Snippets</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Each submenu needs to have an associated UUID inside `<key>...</key>`. I created one from an online UUID [generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4). You can then add the submenu's UUID to the top-level `items` array to add the submenu to your bundle's menu.

Finally, when loading your bundle into textmate you **must** first delete all cached instances of the bundle from:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles
~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles
```

If you don't, textmate will sometimes ignore the newly loaded bundle. Not sure if there's a cleaner way to reload a bundle, but deleting it worked for me.

For a complete example see [this commit](https://github.com/abencz/ROS_tmbundle/commit/615f3a7fa679583b42a66cb11e2ac7173c66a8b9) in the ROS bundle on my Github.

Answer (score 1):

Just some extra info on the excellent answer above

As of TM2 rc23, you can access the UUID of an existing item by right-clicking on it in the bundle editor window (accessed with `cntrl-option-command-B`)

You can create a UUID in `terminal.app` with the command `uuidgen` (you could also make this into a command if you use this often)

TM2 doesn't need the cache clearing - it watches for changes in the plist.

@user96157 is clear about this, but note you have to also add your new submenu to the mainMenu. So:

```
<key>mainMenu</key>
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
    <string>COPY-UUID-FOR-YOUR-NEW-SUB-MENU-HERE!</string>
```